# How to access data from computed property Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue.js and when I try to access a variable from data inside a computed property, it returns `undefined`.
Here's the code:

```
    <script>
     export default {
       name: 'app',
       data: () => {
         return {
           lang: 'sp'
         }
       },
       computed: {
         langEn: () => this.lang === 'en',
         langSp: () => this.lang === 'sp'
       }
     }
    </script>
```

This is in a NPM project. And inside a `.vue` file. Maybe it behaves differently when used like this?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is a very common "gotcha".

Do not use a fat arrow when defining your computed.

When you use a fat arrow to define your computed, methods, or data, you capture `this` lexically and it will point to the containing scope (which is often `window` or undefined) and not your Vue.

```vue
<script>
   export default {
     name: 'app',
     data() {
       return {
         lang: 'sp'
       }
     },
     computed: {
       langEn() { return this.lang === 'en' },
       langSp() { return this.lang === 'sp' }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that save me a lot of time googling

Comment: If your variable starts with _ or $, you may acces your variable like this: `this.$data._name`